# Re-enable editable file path in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-11.04

I'm using Gnome Shell with Ubuntu 11.04. I'm liking it a lot so far, but the only issue is the fact I can't type a file path into Nautilus; I only get the silly breadcrumb buttons. Can someone point me to a solution on how to revert back to having a nice, normal, useful address bar please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This page](http://ismailtaha.com/wp/2011/06/28/switch-to-text-mode-location-bar-at-nautilus-ubuntu-11-04-natty/) explains how to bring back the address bar. In short:

```
$ gconftool-2 --type=Boolean --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/always_use_location_entry true
```

Answer (score 11):

I have not figured out a permanent solution myself, but once you have nautilus open, you can do

```
ctrl + l
```

you will get access to the address bar, and you can type the full file path in there.

Another option would be to type the following when opening nautilus itself, either through the run command (alt+f2) or from console.

```
nautilus path/to/folder
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found this page, the removal of the location bar setting makes me nuts...

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/use-text-mode-location-bar-in-nautilus.html

Answer (score 2):

One more method, in addition to those already given, is to start typing / in nautilus and it will bring up the editable file path.

This seems to me by far the easiest method that makes me not miss the button at all.